# Как задать свой адрес Java сервера на сокетах?

Tags: java, сервер, сокет, localhost

Есть простенький Java сервер на сокетах. Сервер запускается на локальной машине, поэтому для доступа к нему нужно использовать адрес `localhost`. Как сделать доступ к серверу не по имени `localhost`, а по какому-нибудь другому имени, например `example.com`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Вариант 1.*** Доступ к серверу нужен только с локальной машины. В этом случае достаточно внести изменения в файл `%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, вписав в него строку

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
```

***Вариант 2.*** Доступ к серверу нужен с нескольких машин из локальной сети. В этом случае нужно чтобы сервер слушал не только адрес `127.0.0.1`, но и адрес, указанный в настройках сетевой карты. Впрочем, можно не заморачиваться и слушать все адреса (`0.0.0.0`). На остальных машинах нужно также внести изменения в файл `hosts`.

***Вариант 3.*** Нужен доступ из сети Интернет. Это самый сложный случай. Для начала нужен "белый" статический IP-адрес. Этот адрес должен быть либо у сервера, либо у какого-либо устройства, способного "пробрасывать" нужные порты на ваш сервер. Далее у какого-либо регистратора покупаем доменное имя `example.com` и вносим в настройки этого доменного имени так называемую *A-запись*, в которой и будет указан "белый" статический IP-адрес.

Comment: Как во втором варианте сделать, чтобы сервер слушал не только `localhost`?

Comment: Чтобы слушать все адреса, достаточно передать `null` в качестве `InetAddress`. Или просто воспользоваться конструктором без указания адреса: `new ServerSocket(port)`.

Answer (score 4):

Если я правильно понял,в файле hosts у тебя должно быть следующее:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

добавь такую же строку и поменяй `localhost` на то, что тебе нужно

Comment: @kff спасибо за замечание.